# Is there any back up system to recover a deleted form?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have accidentally deleted a form.

Is there any back up system to recover lost forms like this?

I have searched the support and don't see any information on this.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the stated privacy policy for Cognito Forms emphasizes the fact that we immediately honor requests to permanently delete forms and associated entry data.  While Microsoft maintains backups of the data for us across multiple geographically distributed datacenters to prevent accidental loss of data, we do not additionally retain copies to protect against accidental deletion by our customers.

We would like to offer backup options to our customers in the future on an opt-in basis where we still respect people's rights to permanently delete information as may be required to meet local laws or organization policies.  Please up vote and/or comment on this feature on our Idea Board to help us prioritize this feature.

[Ability to backup and restore Cognito Form data.](https://trello.com/c/LqMrPmYe)